# Cant install amdgpu

Tags: command-line, display-resolution, xrandr, error-handling, amdgpu

So Im trying to install ubuntu through a flashdrive but the resolution is so low I cant even see the buttons. I think its my monitors fault because when I connect it to my tv screen it has its full res on. Thing is Im not planning to use my tv as my monitor. So I tried installing amdgpu since xrandr didnt work (told me there was only the current resolution available), but it ALSO doesnt work here is the log

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04$ '77-ubuntu-20.04$ '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-20.2/home/ubuntu/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04/amdgpu-install'
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS *Focal Fossa* - Release amd64 (20200731) focal InRelease
Obter:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Atingido:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS *Focal Fossa* - Release amd64 (20200731) focal Release
Ign:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Obter:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Obter:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Obter:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Atingido:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obter:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Atingido:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Baixados 109 kB em 1s (89,8 kB/s)
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Versão seleccionada '20.20-1098277' (localhost [all]) para 'amdgpu-pin'
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
amdgpu-pin
0 pacotes atualizados, 1 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 396 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 0 B/2.684 B de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 25,6 kB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Obter:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pin 20.20-1098277 [2.684 B]
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado amdgpu-pi
n.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 187886 ficheiros e directórios actu
almente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../amdgpu-pin_20.20-1098277_all
.deb ...
A descompactar amdgpu-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Configurando amdgpu-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que
você solicitou uma situação impossível ou, se você está usando a
distribuição instável, que alguns pacotes requeridos não foram
criados ainda ou foram retirados da "Incoming".
A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
amdgpu : Depende: amdgpu-lib (= 20.20-1098277) mas não será instalado
amdgpu-lib32 : Depende: amdgpu-lib (= 20.20-1098277) mas não será instalado ou
amdgpu-lib-hwe (= 20.20-1098277) mas não é instalável
Depende: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.100-1098277)
Depende: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.100-1098277)
Depende: libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:10.0-1098277)
Depende: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
Depende: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.

What should I do? Any clues?

Comment: FOrgot to add. Im on a ryzen 5 3400g, 2x4gb ram, vega 11, VGA 1440x900 monitor, moba is a320m-hd

Comment: I did as the instructions said. extracted amdgpu.tar.gz, then ran the command

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?  If you have info to add edit the question rather then make comment. Also many wont be able to help you as none of that info is in English.

Comment: Looks like he's using 20.04, and the version 20.20 of the AMD drivers, which is outdated - the latest one is currently 20.45.
Even, the latest AMD GPU drivers (20.45) won't work, however - they don' compile with the latest Linux kernel version 5.8.0-40, which is used by Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @axel22 yes, I'm using 20.04. What should I do then?

Comment: I recently built a new system with an AMD W5500 GPU, and I installed Ubuntu 20.04.
OpenGL works with the generic mesa drivers that come with Ubuntu 20.04.
OpenCL is, however, not supported with the generic drivers.
If you want to use the AMD drivers, then people claim that this works if you downgrade your kernel to e.g. 5.4.0-56. You could try doing this manually, or you could install an earlier Ubuntu version with an earlier kernel. Disclaimer: I did not personally try this on my machine, and I don't know if it will work.